# Installing Android Automotive OS

Tags: android-automotive

How can I deploy android automotive os into an embedded board like raspberry pi?

What I want to do is develop an app for my application on top of android automotive os.

Comment: There is an emulator with Android Automotive if you want to develop an app that supports Android Automotive. It's available in Android Studio.

Comment: That is the later part. First, I want to install it. Being a beginner, I have no clue. Is it he regular android os with some added features?

Comment: It's the regular AOSP with some package replacements and additional services that can connect to the car.

Comment: Thank you, @fejd for the clarification.

Comment: any update if this can be ported to raspberry pi?

Comment: I have stopped working on this for the time being, but as far as I have understood, Android Automotive is (Android + packages which make working with usual vehicle components possible), like working with CAN. 

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-android-raspberry-pi/ from this post, I do see a number of android for Raspberry Pi OS, but not sure how to add the Android Automotive layer to it.

Comment: It simpler approach is to use AOSP on an already supported Android device. AOSP has Android Automotive built in (if you configure it that way).

Answer (score 3):

> How can I deploy android automotive os into an embedded board like raspberry pi?

There is no simple answer to your question. This is no simple task, and you just can't Google it. There are some ports of generic Android (phone/tablet version) for RPi and you will have to just go through them and make the changes as per your needs.

Most importantly, you need to come up with the kernel and Board Support Package (BSP) for RPi that enables its peripherals and drivers etc.

Here's something to get you started:

#### Android Automotive OS on Pixel 3 XL

https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/start/pixel3

From the link above:

> To build packages specific to Automotive, run:

```
m android.hardware.automotive.audiocontrol@1.0-service
android.hardware.automotive.vehicle@2.0-service
```

#### Codelabs: Developing for the Android Automotive OS Platform

Here's the Codelabs for step by step instruction from Google I/O 2019
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/automotive-getting-started/#0

#### Android Kernel and BSP

If you want to browse through the kernel and bsp packages from Android source - 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/bsp

---

One important thing to note is, Android Automotive OS developer program is little different from developing apps for phones. For Android Auto OS, many of the docs and dev tools are not in public domain and are available to car related companies and partners - in other words your company or org needs to partner with Google.

While this may not be the exact answer you are looking for, but I hope this helps you get started in the right direction.